# Add robots.txt to root

Tags: configuration, robots.txt

I have a new Wordpress 3.5.1 install (hosted on Dreamhost FWIW) that I do **not** want to be indexed by search engines. I would like to serve a simple robots.txt with `Disallow: /` for all user agents.

I have checked the "Discourage search engines from indexing this site" box on the Settings > Reading menu, but http://mysite.com/robots.txt still returns a 404.

Is there a way to have Wordpress automatically generate and serve an appropriate robots.txt file? If not, what is the best way to configure it to serve my own static robots.txt file?

Comment: I just realized that the "Discourage search engines from indexing this site" setting adds a `<meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots">` to the head section of each page which should accomplish my goal. I'd still like to know how to add a robots.txt too though.

Comment: Can't you just manually upload a `robots.txt` over FTP? WordPress doesn't use it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in order for Wordpress to generate a robots.txt for you you must be using a non-default permalink structure. Make sure you've selected an option in the Settings > Permalinks menu.

Also, if a robots.txt file exists at your root directory it will override the setting in Wordpress. It looks like you already have a robots.txt file and that is the reason the wordpress setting is ignored.

Comment: I don't already have a robots.txt, but adding one does resolve the issue. When I delete the robots.txt off the server I get a 404 when requesting /robots.txt

Comment: lol, your valid url confused me. robots.txt is genrerated by wordpress only if you use pretty permalinks, do you?

Comment: good call, that was the problem. I hadn't yet set up a permalink structure and was using the default. After I selected the "Post name" option in the Permalinks Settings menu robots.txt started working as expected.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to add `robots.txt` file to the root of your site. `robots.txt` file is generated in real time, when you visit `http://mysite.com/robots.txt`. The function, responsible for creation of this file, is [`do_robots`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L1062).

If you wish to add your own directives, just write your hook for `robots_txt` filter, like this:

```
add_filter( 'robots_txt', 'wpse8170_my_robots_txt', 10, 2 );
function wpse8170_my_robots_txt( $output, $public ) {
    if ( '0' != $public ) {
        $output .= '
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins
Disallow: /wp-content/cache
Disallow: /wp-content/themes
';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: You say "robots.txt file is generated in real time, when you visit http://mysite.com/robots.txt", but that's not happening for me. I'm getting a 404 when visiting that URL.

Comment: `robots.txt` is generated only if you use pretty permalinks. So to make it working go to Settings > Permalinks and select permalink structure you, which you need.